# listen foundation toggler in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, zurb-foundation

I have had a close button using the foundation Toggler

https://get.foundation/sites/docs/toggler.html

How in JS could i do something to the DOM when the close button is clicked?

I have tried something like this:

```js
function handleToggler() {
  console.log('closing the panel');
}

window.addEventListener(
  'on.zf.toggler',
  handleToggler,
);
```

But this is not it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onclick to the html:

```
<a data-toggle="menuBar" onclick="yourFunctionHere()">Expand!</a>
```

Then just access the DOM node you want to do something to in the function:

```
function yourFunctionHere(e){
    const a_div = document.getElementById("a_div");
}
```